# Registering screen change in python?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

So using **tkinter** I have made a simple program that changes the color of all shapes on the canvas to a random color every second ,what I am looking for is a way to register every screen change and write down the time between screen changes in a separate file.I also need to do it without the help of too many external libraries if possible.

My code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -W ignore::DeprecationWarning
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox
import time
import random


colors = ['DarkOrchid1','chocolate3','gold2','khaki2','chartreuse2','deep pink','white','grey','orange']
top = Tkinter.Tk()
global b
b=0
C = Tkinter.Canvas(top, bg="blue", height=600, width=800)
bcg1=C.create_rectangle(0,0,800,100,fill=random.choice(colors))
bcg2=C.create_rectangle(0,100,800,200,fill=random.choice(colors))
bcg3=C.create_rectangle(0,200,800,300,fill=random.choice(colors))
bcg4=C.create_rectangle(0,300,800,400,fill=random.choice(colors))
bcg5=C.create_rectangle(0,400,800,500,fill=random.choice(colors))
bcg6=C.create_rectangle(0,500,800,600,fill=random.choice(colors))
bcgs=[bcg1,bcg2,bcg3,bcg4,bcg5,bcg6]
coord = 10, 50, 240, 210
rect1=C.create_rectangle(0,0,100,100,fill="green")
rect2=C.create_rectangle(700,500,800,600,fill="green")
rect3=C.create_rectangle(0,500,100,600,fill="green")
rect4=C.create_rectangle(700,0,800,100,fill="green")
def color():
    global b
    global bcgs
    global color
    if b==0:
        C.itemconfig(rect1,fill='green')
        C.itemconfig(rect2,fill='green')
        C.itemconfig(rect3,fill='green')
        C.itemconfig(rect4,fill='green')
        b=1
        count=0
        for i in range(len(bcgs)):
            C.itemconfig(bcgs[i],fill=random.choice(colors))

    elif b==1:
        C.itemconfig(rect1,fill='red')
        C.itemconfig(rect2,fill='red')
        C.itemconfig(rect3,fill='red')
        C.itemconfig(rect4,fill='red')
        b=0
        for i in range(len(bcgs)):
            C.itemconfig(bcgs[i],fill=random.choice(colors))


    top.after(2000, color)

C.pack()
color()
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean "screen change"? You have this set to change colors every 2 seconds, did you mean you want to verify that this is taking 2 seconds to complete?

Comment: (On a sidenote, you might want to un your code thought `autopep8`)

Comment: yes this is exactly what i aim to do ,I want to confirm that i does not take any additional time and if it does how much exactly

Answer (score 1):

Unless you use a real time OS, you will never get perfect timing. You can bank on being a few milliseconds off the mark. To see how much, you can calculate the difference in `time.time()`. For the best accuracy, move the `after` call to the first thing in the function.

That plus some other improvements:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -W ignore::DeprecationWarning
import Tkinter
import time
import random
from itertools import cycle

colors = ['DarkOrchid1','chocolate3','gold2','khaki2','chartreuse2','deep pink','white','grey','orange']
rect_colors = cycle(['green', 'red'])

top = Tkinter.Tk()
C = Tkinter.Canvas(top, bg="blue", height=600, width=800)
bcg1=C.create_rectangle(0,0,800,100,fill=random.choice(colors))
bcg2=C.create_rectangle(0,100,800,200,fill=random.choice(colors))
bcg3=C.create_rectangle(0,200,800,300,fill=random.choice(colors))
bcg4=C.create_rectangle(0,300,800,400,fill=random.choice(colors))
bcg5=C.create_rectangle(0,400,800,500,fill=random.choice(colors))
bcg6=C.create_rectangle(0,500,800,600,fill=random.choice(colors))
bcgs=[bcg1,bcg2,bcg3,bcg4,bcg5,bcg6]
coord = 10, 50, 240, 210
rect1=C.create_rectangle(0,0,100,100,fill="green")
rect2=C.create_rectangle(700,500,800,600,fill="green")
rect3=C.create_rectangle(0,500,100,600,fill="green")
rect4=C.create_rectangle(700,0,800,100,fill="green")
rects = [rect1,rect2,rect3,rect4]

last_time = time.time()
def color():
    top.after(2000, color)
    global last_time

    rect_color = next(rect_colors)
    for item in rects:
        C.itemconfig(item, fill=rect_color)
    for item in bcgs:
        C.itemconfig(item, fill=random.choice(colors))

    print("{} seconds since the last run".format(time.time() - last_time))
    last_time = time.time()

C.pack()
color()
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply the time is calculated just as I wanted it to be but , wont this just measure the time it took for this part of the code to execute and compare it to the previous ?
I am not sure how to express exactly what I am going for so I will give an example , lets say you have a computer that for some reason has e seemingly random GUI lag ,so i want to measure the time that would take for the GUI to refresh in this particular case for the colors in the tkinter window to change . So what i am going for is a way to determine if the pixels have of the tkinter window have changed.

Comment: This measures the time it takes from one update to the next. If you have a GUI lag then it may show up here, depending on where the lag is coming from. If you are watching via RDP then this won't register the lag. If your processor is locking up then it will.

Comment: Yes i am watchig via RDP but i think that the CPU is not at fault here

Comment: Then I'll bet the lag is in the RDP connection, and has nothing to do with the program.